# Converting existing integer identities to GUID

Tags: sql, nhibernate, guid, azure-sql-database

I am using NHibernate on my project and preparing a new version to release. I read about GUID.COMB and HI/LO is faster than database generated identities. Then, I decided to move on GUID.COMB but I don't know how to convert existing primary keys to GUID without breaking table relations.

I need advices please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the database... but you basically need to:

- Drop FKs
- Drop PKs
- (optionally) rename the old columns
- Create new Guid columns
- Create PKs using the new columns
- Re-establish the data relationships for the new columns using joins with the old ones
- Create the new FKs

Comment: OK... I haven't used it, so I don't know whether all the steps will work. You'll have to try (I suggest you create a couple dummy tables and try it before starting with your production data)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me, it is the only logical way since there are no different answers. :)